# Evaluate the probability of my experiment being deteministic AKA what tis the chance of something which has never happened happening?

Tags: probability, deterministic

Short version

Imagine I run the exact same experiment $n$ independent times and get $n$ times the same result. Can you put a lower bound on the probability of getting the same result the $n+1$ time I run the experiment?

---

Long version

I'd like to check that a computer program is deterministic and I don't want to read the code to go looking for potential bugs (race conditions ...). I'd like to estimate the probability of the code being error free. If I run it $n$ times and get $2$ different answer or more, I know something went from at some point.

However, if I get $n$ times the same answer, what is the probability of the code being error free?

I'm sure someone somewhere did some math on it, I just don't know how to find it.

Comment: Good question, +1, though I don't know whether you will get an answer. [Obligatory xkcd comic here.](https://www.xkcd.com/1132/)

Comment: See threads about the ["Rule of Three"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=rule+of+three).